# OpenWRT LAN clients don't see each

Tags: networking, lan, openwrt

I'm a beginner at using OpenWRT but I'm loving it already. Everything is running fine (internet, wifi) on all clients except one thing: the computers running in my LAN don't see each other. Pings to them or between them gives "destination host unreachable". This happens when using either the machine's IP's or their assigned hostnames.

Running Backfire 10.03.1 - default settings everywhere except of course for the specific ISP stuff in the WAN.

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it!

Basically each LAN port was acting independently - they needed to be part of the same VLAN. This is accomplished by appending this into `/etc/config/network` and then restarting:

```
config switch eth0                   
   option reset 1                     
   option enable_vlan 1             

config switch_vlan
   option device eth0          
   option vlan 1               
   option ports "0 1 2 3 4 5"
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Would you mind posting your entire `/etc/config/network`?

Answer (score 0):

You have an option in OpenWRT which "secure" each LAN client appart from each others. It is a common feature on lots of WiFi routers.

Depending of the way you configure your box, it is `isolate` setting into `/etc/config/wireless`.

Have a look at http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/wireless

Comment: my problem pertains to wired clients as well. I can disable wifi altogether and same things happens...